# i have multiple .sql files containing arabic values ,when i run them all using sqlcmd in .bat file the arabic not recognized in the data base

Tags: batch-file, command-line, sqlcmd, arabic-support

```
Ord_Depot      Ord_Product
---------   ------------
ط§ظ„ط¬ظٹظ„ظٹ    ط¨ظ†ط²ظٹظ†
```

the result of running the .sql files using sqlcmd
i want it to accept arabic lang
knowing that when i run each .sql file individually using sql server management studio it works fine

Here is my current `batch-file`

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S LAPTOP-4L4R4VC3\SQLEXPRESS /d master -E -i "%%G"
pause
```

Comment: Please delete your comment above, and instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63231810/edit) to include any pertinent information. When you add your code, please use the appropriate formatting method to place it into a code block too. It would also help if you explain to us what your current codepage is, what locale/language you're using, and which specific version of Windows you're wanting this solution for.

Comment: Can you set the code page to unicode `CHCP 65001>nul` and tell me the results ?

Comment: Sorry didnt work ,same result as before

Answer (score 1):

Set your code page to `1256` to accept Arabic characters using command `chcp 1256`

```
@echo off
chcp 1256
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S LAPTOP-4L4R4VC3\SQLEXPRESS /d master -E -i "%%~G"
pause>nul
```

Comment: still having the same problem

Comment: ok, I see your question was corrected now. What encoding is your `.sql` files saved as?

Comment: open `cmd` then type `chcp 1256` and chose one of your files and run `type filename.sql` and show me a screenshot.